# How to add a missing database to an AlwaysOn Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

Setup:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012, and we have 3 production servers(prod1, prod2, prod3) with AlwaysOn.

We recently added a new database and the new database was added to our Availability Group(named SQG01) on servers prod1, prod3.  For whatever reason the new database was not added on prod2.  All other existing databases on prod1,2,3 are all setup and running correctly.

Before adding the new database to the AG on prod2, should I do a restore to "catch up" the new database on prod2 so that it's at least close to the other 2.  We do nightly backups of our production(for restoring to dev/qa environments), so I would use the previous night and it shouldn't miss too many records.

Or should I just add it in and let AlwaysOn sync it up.

I'm not too familiar with AlwaysOn.

Comment: Check this - [SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn: need to automatically add databases by script- T-sql or PowerShell](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40275/8783) to see if it helps. I am not too sure if this post should be a duplicate of the former one.. so will let the mods decide.

Comment: This is more of a one time instance.  Although looking through your script we may use it going forward, to keep this from happening again(we don't create DBs very often).  Thanks for the heads up on the link/script!